# How does Qt determine which widgets gets the mouse events?

Tags: qt, user-interface

Something I have been curious about is how Qt determines which widgets get the mouse events. I'm guessing that it keeps track of the current widget, which is how it decides which one gets click events. But how does it determine the current widget, and as an extension, mouse enter and leave events? Does it iterate through each top level widget and check if the cursor falls within the widget's bounding rect? And then ask all children of that widget, etc.?

I have been searching through the Qt source code but haven't been able to find where all of this starts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The trick is not to search through the code, but to trace through it: build your own Qt, run any application, and add a breakpoint at all [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245(v=vs.85).aspx) in the implementation of `QAbstractEventDispatcher` (IIRC `QWindowsEventDispatcher` or somesuch).

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, I think this is the path I'm going to take. I've been meaning to dig more into the Qt source to learn anyways, and I guess building it and messing around is the best way to achieve that.